# XSLT - retrieving an XMl tag value without its inner tags

Tags: xslt, xpath, xml-parsing

I have an xml that looks like this:

```
<OuterTag> outerVal
   <Name> value1 </Name>
   <Desc> value2 </Desc>
</OuterTag>
```

and I want to retrieve the value of the outer tag ("outerVal").
when I use

```
xsl:value-of select="OuterTag" />
```

I get "outerValvalue1value2".
How can i retrieve only the outer value?

Comment: +1 for basic question I defined as community wiki

Answer (score 1):

A complete solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(OuterTag/text()[1])" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
outerVal
```

**Note:** Whitespace is significant inside XML elements. Here's a stylesheet that reveals the placement/structure of the text nodes in `OuterTag` and its children:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="OuterTag/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('[', ., ']')" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="OuterTag/*/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('(', ., ')')" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
[ outerVal
   ]( value1 )[
   ]( value2 )[
]
```

Adding `normalize-space`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="OuterTag/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('[', normalize-space(), ']')" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="OuterTag/*/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('(', normalize-space(), ')')" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces the following result:

```
[outerVal](value1)[](value2)[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try text():

```
<xsl:value-of select="OuterTag/text()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `<xsl:value-of select="OuterTag/text()"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Adapt this xpath to your context

```
 "/Outertag/text()[1]"
```

This will retrieve the first text node of the Outertag root node. The other answers show you how to get all text children nodes of Outertag context node.