# xPath between nodes

Tags: xml, dom, object, xpath

Ok say I had a document in the format of:

```
<root>
    <item>
        <sometag>
        </sometag>    
    </item>
    Text I want to grab
    <someweirdtag>
    </someweirdtag>
</root>
```

Is there any way I can get "Text I want to grab" from between the nodes using xPath?

Comment: For future reference, "nodes" in XPath refers to several other things besides elements. The text you want to grab *is* a node (or is the content of a text node). I think what you're trying to say is, you want to get the text between some elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposed XML:

```
<root>
    <item>
        <sometag>
        </sometag>

    </item>
    Text I want to grab
    <someweirdtag>
    </someweirdtag>
</root>
```

XPath:

```
root/text()
```

Result: `Text I want to grab`

Reference: [XSLT - retrieving an XMl tag value without its inner tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744077/xslt-retrieving-an-xml-tag-value-without-its-inner-tags)